# Proper margin layout in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm confused if my code is right or not, for now when I run my app under android version 10 it works well, this is the result I want and it works fine when I run [image: Result]

but the problem is I don't think if I run this app to the other version of android it will work or I think the design of `textviews` and ImageView will be scattered since when I've tried to view the design of the XML it looks like this [image: ViewInAndroidStudio]

I've put it inside Gridview. It's very helpful for me as a newbie in `android` if someone can help me.

*Main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:id="@+id/imgFood"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/round_outline"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:id="@+id/imgId"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imgFood"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/round_outline"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtCcText"
    android:text="Cash Card number:"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:hint="Cash Card no."
    android:textColor="@color/primary"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgId"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-11dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:text="Cash Card number"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgId"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtHHno"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-11dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:text="Household number:"
    android:textColor="@color/primary"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtPrice"
    android:text="HHNumber"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtHHno"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgId"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtSeries"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtPrice"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-11dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
    android:text="Series number:"
    android:textColor="@color/primary"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtSeriesNumber"
    android:text="SeriesNumber"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtSeries"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgId"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

*GridView.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
>

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/background"
        app:liftOnScroll="true"/>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<GridView
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:columnWidth="300dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I will suggest you use RecyclerView with ConstraintLayout or lazyColumn with jetpack compose.

Comment: @Vidyesh Churi Thanks for your response, but is there any way just using GridView? since I already used GridView

Comment: Maybe two imageViews with one linearLayout will do the job with the weight distribution of 1:1:2 respectively.

Comment: @Vidyesh Churi Thanks for the response but I don't have idea how to implement it , please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgFood"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgId"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCcText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Cash Card no."
        android:text="Cash Card number:"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1234-5678-9000-0000"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHHno"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Household number:"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPrice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="123-4567"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSeries"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Series number:"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSeriesNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1234567890"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No problem - CarlJade